# mouseMove not working in firefox; giving http method not allowed

Tags: firefox, protractor, e2e-testing, geckodriver

`mouseMove` is not working in firefox with the latest versions of `Firefox, geckodriver, and protractor`. Same code works fine for `chrome 77`.

I have the following environment:

> Node:  v10.16.3
>
> Protractor:  5.4.2
>
> Geckodriver: v0.25.0
>
> firefox: 69.0.1 (64-bit)

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.xpath('//app-admin-panel/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]'))).perform();
```

This code snippet should hover over the specified element, but it throws the following error:

```
  Message:
    Failed: HTTP method not allowed
  Stack:
    WebDriverError: HTTP method not allowed
        at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:536:11)
        at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    From: Task: mouseMove
        at Driver.schedule (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:807:17)
        at actions.map.action (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\actions.js:124:23)
        at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        at C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\actions.js:123:29
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
        at C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    From: Task: ActionSequence.perform
        at ActionSequence.perform (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\actions.js:122:33)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (E:\Office\Protractor\Wallboard\Smoketest.js:39:207)
        at C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:112:25
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1077:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2505:12)
        at schedulerExecute (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:95:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2974:25)
        at C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
    From: Task: Run it("Make a Copy of Dashboard") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hassan Sohail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:19)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (E:\Office\Protractor\Wallboard\Smoketest.js:38:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Office\Protractor\Wallboard\Smoketest.js:2:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)

4 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 21.836 seconds

[11:41:20] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:41:20] I/launcher - firefox #01 failed 1 test(s)
[11:41:20] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[11:41:20] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue (not sure if they fixed it yet) for FF.
I suggest you to use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-firefox-support

Comment: Can you also share the link of the Issue? 
I would like to track it, but I couldn't find the exact one

Answer (score 1):

solved by updating direct connect value to false in protractor config
*in case of chrome set it to true for local testing*

> directConnect: false